Blender showing hidden mesh in sculpt mode
I'm making a weld effect and have and issue when I want to apply limited dissolve afterwards.
To make the weld, I hide the rest of the mesh (thin panel), and sculpt with Dynotopo:

(The black line is a directional light)
When I tab into Edit mode (in Sculpting workspace), Blender shows all verts:

Only the unhidden faces are rendered. All shading modes show all vertices, and only shade the unhidden faces from my original selection.
Selecting all with A, selects everything including hidden verts.
I will manually select what I need to limit dissolve. But this seems like a bug to me.
Blender version is 4.4
Thanks
Update:
It seems like problems are mainly from using Dynotopo. After doing the limited dissolve, I realised all the edges/ faces of the mesh are messed up.
See this before and after sculpting Dynotopia, with most of mesh hidden, it goes a bit crazy.
Before:

After


I solved this a minute after posting the question, but it still seems like a bug to me.
To get the selection I want:

Select all with A, it will select everything including the hidden verts shown.
Cycle through the select modes, using 1, 2, 3, when you cycle to faces mode, it will change the selection to only the original unhidden mesh (rest verts will still be shown, but become unselected).
Cycle once more to vertex mode using 1, and it will select verts for those selected faces

Answer to update:
The issue with Dynotopo messing up the whole mesh I resolved using these steps:

Select the faces for sculpt target, P > Selection, to separate the faces to a new object
Switch to Sculpt mode and sculpt the object, using Dynotopo
Clean up with limited dissolve/ merge by distance
Switch to Object mode and rejoin to previous mesh with Ctrl + J
Do merge by distance one more time


This solves the issue for limited dissolve, but there is another issue for this question, have updated the question.
